# Best practice when using similar code in methods

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

I have a Utility method to comunicate with an API, it communicates using a POST HTTP request, in my utility-class i have a method called:

```
(void)makeConnectionWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters;
```

wich takes the parameters and sets up the body of the POST. however, in one particular case i want to upload some images and the code is slightly altered to make uploading of said images possible, what is the best practice for this case? should i rename the method to:

```
(void)makeConnectionWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters andImages(NSArray*)images;
```

and set nil as a parameter in all other cases, or should i set a bool in the method calling "makeConnectionWithParameters" and check in the method if the bool is set and in that case process the images?

Any other ideas to make the code prettier?

here is the method:

```
(void)makeConnectionWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:20];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSString *boundary = @"myR4ND0Mboundary";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //Lägg till inloggningsuppgifter för API-anropet
    [parameters setValue:API_LOGIN forKey:@"api-login"];
    [parameters setValue:API_PASSWORD forKey:@"api-password"];

    //Lägg till alla parameterar i POST-bodyn
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    for (NSString *param in parameters) 
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    if(hasImages)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(UIImage* image in self.images)
        {
            c++;
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
            if (imageData) 
            {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", c]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:imageData];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
            imageData = nil;
        }
    }

    //Sätt content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];
    }
}
```

I hope this all makes sense. :)

Comment: Why don't you put the images in the parameters and use only one method?

Comment: because the "content-disposition" bit is a little different and I thought the code got a bit ugly. I've already solved it, but i wanted to use my code more as a base for discussion.

Comment: I personally would make a method where you need to provide the body as NSData.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, then one could use two different methods for appending the data to the body. one where you have the normal parameters and one where you use the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create two methods that make the request objects, not the actual connections:

```
(NSMutableURLRequest*)makeConnectionWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters;
(NSMutableURLRequest*)makeConnectionWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters andImages(NSArray*)images;
```

Inside the first method call:

```
[self makeConnectionWithParameters:parameters andImages:nil];
```

...and have a nil check for the images inside the second method. Use those two methods to get your request then make the NSURLConnection with the returned object.